# how to use locations,startPoint,endPoint of CAGradientLayer?

Tags: ios, cagradientlayer

I have try to use `CAGradientLayer` as a background color, but I can not understand what the properties of `CAGradientLayer` mean.  Then I can't do a cool effect.  So how can I use them?

Comment: The documentation has everything you need: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It really doesn't. This question could be better defined, but the documentation lacks clarity. If I have a two color gradient and want to define the locations of color boundaries, do I define an array of one location (the middle), three locations (start, middle, end), or four locations (start1, end1, start2, end2). All could be valid, and no explanation is offered.